# Python: Accessing specific sublist element

Tags: python, sublist

Is there a way to be able to access specific sublist element?

**For example:**

```
list = [["a","b"],["c","d"]]
```

how to print out only `b`??

Thanks!

Comment: a) don't call it list (list is a thing in python).  b) to access 'b'    list[0][1]

Comment: you can do `list[0][1]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) to know more

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is a bad practice to name a variable as `list` as it is a keyword in Python. Say, it is changed to lis

```
lis = [["a","b"],["c","d"]]
```

To access b, you need to first get to the first element of `lis`, by `lis[0]`. This gives `["a", "b"]`. Now you need to further go into it, so you do `lis[0][1]`, This gives the 1-indexed element of `lis[0]`, i.e., 'b'

Comment: `list` is *not* a keyword (unlike, say, `if` or `while`); it is however a name of a predefined class; so it may be overwritten, it is simply a bad idea to do so.

Comment: Thanks @Błotosmętek for letting me know

Answer (score -1):

You need to select the first sublist in your `list` (index 0), and then the second element of your sublist (index 1).

Result is `list[0][1]`.